# SPD and external content type for Oracle

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm trying BCS in SharePoint designer 2010. Is it possible to create external content type for Oracle ? In the data source drop down I can see only ".NET Type" , "SQL Server" and "WCF Service" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Web Service yourself which connects to your External System and use that using SharePoint Designer:

The company I work for has a tool called BCS Meta Man which will generate a .Net or Database model for you, it's a Visual Studio Extension:

[BCS Meta Man](http://www.lightningtools.com/bcs/bcs-meta-man.aspx)
[BCS Meta Man + Oracle walkthrough](http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/01/21/business-connectivity-services-and-oracle-with-bcs-meta-man.aspx)

You can use just the normal Visual Studio BCS Model Project to make the Model manually, but you'll probably notice very quickly that it's quite a steep learning curve:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464424(office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Phill. I've done it using Visual Studio . I blogged it here,

http://sharepointjournals.wordpress.com/